# Failing to send image to Go server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, go, fetch, mux

Recently I started working with Go to make servers, in my current experiment I am trying to upload an image to my Go/mux webserver via fetch on a React.js front-end. Whenever I upload an image through a form the server fails to receive the image and returns a "no such file" error. I am using JS's FormData API to store and send the image.

Here is the code for the client

```
handleInput = (e) => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("myImage", e.target.files)
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/api", {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    })
    .then((res) => {
       console.log(res)
    })
    .then(() => {
       console.log("Success")
      })
    .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  }
```

Here is the code for the server

```
func api(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

    fmt.Println("Connected -> api route")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "connected to api")

    // ERROR HERE: no such file / failed to retrieve image
    r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20)
    file, _, err := r.FormFile("myImage")
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        fmt.Println("failed to retrieve image")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    } else if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("Success")
    }

    defer file.Close()
}
```

I have tried adding and removing the multipart/form-data headers, neither have worked.

I'm new to Go and still trying to figure things out, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you see the error on the POST request or on the OPTIONS request that precedes it? The OPTIONS request won't contain a body (as expected).

Comment: @Peter I'm not seeing any errors on the POST request, the browser is not catching any errors and returns "Success", the only error I see is the one returned by the server on the console which reads "no such file"

Comment: you can try to dump the request object on the server side to inspect it https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequest

Answer (score 0):

Checking the code, this is a pretty standard upload file method, is your Go api working with other services?, I can not find anything wrong, so maybe is more about how the api is configured in general.

Other thing you can do is handling the error at

```
if err := r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20); err != nil {
fmt.Println(err)
}
```

maybe you can have a better idea about the error

Also make sure your file is really there before appending it

```
console.log(e.target.files)
```

Comment: I've tried the latter, I've made sure the file exists on the client before sending it, and I've checked to see if there is an error at r.ParseMultipartForm. Still no luck, there are no errors at the r.ParseMultipartForm either. Thanks for the insight anyway

Comment: Holy crap that was the solution